# Using adduser to create a user with group, home directory and gecos as arguments

Tags: linux, shell-script, fedora, linux-mint

I want to create a user with adduser command and then set up its password using passwd command.

I want to specify the group, home directory and gecos for the user and then set up the password for the user using passwd command.

If I have stored string values for username, group, home directory, gecos, password in variables un, grp, hd, g and pd respectively, how can I use adduser and passwd commands to create a user with specified information. I know there's another command "useradd" but I want to use "adduser" at this point. 
How to do this in a shell script?

Comment: This answer is old, but it should still work (has answers for both `useradd` and `adduser`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script

Comment: @ajgringo619 thanks. What should I do about creating user with group, home directory and gecos as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

```
useradd --home /path/to/home \
    --ingroup groupname \
    --gecos "Stuff" username

passwd username
```

https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/adduser/adduser.8.de.html

Comment: I want to know how to do it using adduser.

Comment: actually its adduser, i just typed useradd for whatever reason i dont know... If you would have opened the manpage you would have seen it tho..